# Errors using gender_df and gender functions

Tags: r, function

I have some data with names and birth years, but not sex. Here is a random sample of the data, with made-up birth years (range of actual  birth years in the data is 1909-1999).

Using [gender package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gender), I would like to add a new column, using the *gender* or *gender_df* functions, that is the percent of people with that first name, year of birth pair who are female. However, I am having trouble using both functions.

Here is some sample data:

```
name<-c("Jennifer", "Alison", "PEDER", "Asheng", "Aaron","Jody","Miranda","MARY", "Mitchel", "Renee")
name<-as.character(name)
yob<-c(1984,1987,1986,1979,1963,1952,1983,1948,1938,1952)
df<-data.frame(name,yob)
```

Here is my attempt using *gender_df*:

```
library("gender") # v0.5.1

sex_ssa<-gender_df(df,name_col=df$name,year_col=df$yob,method="ssa")
```

Result:

```
Error: name_col %in% names(data) are not all TRUE
```

Here is my attempt using *gender*:

```
sex_ssa_other<-gender(df$name,
       method = "ssa",
       years = df$yob) %>%
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)
```

Result:

```
Error in gender(df$name, method = "ssa", years = df$yob) : 
  Data must be a character vector.
```

New to R, and imagine I am making a rudimentary mistake. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Where from did you get `gender_df` function?

Comment: I believe gender_df is part of the "gender" package, v 0.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always check documentation for the function you are using.

```
sex_ssa<-gender_df(df,name_col="name",year_col="yob",method="ssa")


> sex_ssa
Source: local data frame [9 x 6]

      name proportion_male proportion_female gender year_min year_max
     (chr)           (dbl)             (dbl)  (chr)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1  Mitchel          1.0000            0.0000   male     1938     1938
2     MARY          0.0023            0.9977 female     1948     1948
3     Jody          0.1700            0.8300 female     1952     1952
4    Renee          0.0070            0.9930 female     1952     1952
5    Aaron          0.9939            0.0061   male     1963     1963
6  Miranda          0.0030            0.9970 female     1983     1983
7 Jennifer          0.0038            0.9962 female     1984     1984
8    PEDER          1.0000            0.0000   male     1986     1986
9   Alison          0.0054            0.9946 female     1987     1987
```

Comment: Ah, crud, thanks for the pointer. Was incorrectly specifying the arguments in the function. Had looked at the documentation, but still managed to mess it up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. First, when you create the data frame, `name` becomes type factor instead of type character. Try this instead (I use `df1` as a data frame name, not `df`):

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jennifer", "Alison", "PEDER", "Asheng", "Aaron", "Jody", "Miranda", "MARY", "Mitchel", "Renee"),
                  yob  = c(1984, 1987, 1986, 1979, 1963, 1952, 1983, 1948, 1938, 1952),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Second, you're using `gender_df()` incorrectly. See the answer by @Rushabh for the correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you, agree with both, and have added the "stringsAsFactors = FALSE" clause to my data.frame command.